# Do many homogeneous polynomials help in faster integer root extraction?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, computational-complexity, sums-of-squares, elimination-theory

Given $n$ homogeneous algebraically independent total degree $2$ polynomials with no $x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2$ variable in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with promise that it has non-zero integer roots with coordinates of $O(n)$ bits in magnitude we can **extract at least one common integer root** with elimination theory in exponential $SPACE$ and $TIME$.

Suppose we have $m\geq n$ homogeneous independent total degree $2$ polynomials with no $x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2$ variable in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with promise that it has non-zero integer roots with coordinates of $O(n)$ bits in magnitude and with

1. any $n$ of them being algebraically independent
2. only common roots of all $m$ polynomials being integer roots

then does it help improve extracting at least one integer root to subexponential $SPACE$ and $TIME$ complexity where input size is $L$ bits (measure of number of coefficients and number of bits in coefficients) at some $m=\Omega(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for a fixed $\epsilon\in(0,\infty)$ (gaussian elimination picks something integral without relevance to non-linear properties)?

Comment: why would one always have an integer root? excluding 0, naturally, as you work with homogeneous polynomials you always will have 0 as a common root.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Promise Problem. We assume things in input in promise problem.