# Does positivstellensatz and SOS proof system help here?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sums-of-squares, quadratic-programming, compressed-sensing, elimination-theory

I have a system of $m$ homogeneous degree $2$ polynomial equations in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ where $m=poly(n)$. Take
$$f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$$
$$\dots$$
$$f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$$
to be the system.

Typically such a system has $\emptyset$ intersection. In my case by design there are common roots that have integer coordinates and only these integer coordinated roots are the common solution.

Since degree is $2$ we have rank $1$ solution which if sparse then is probably amenable to compressed sensing type approaches. In my case the rank $1$ solutions are non-sparse.

> Does Putinar's/Stengle's Positivstellensatz + SOS proof systems help?

**MAIN PROBLEM 1** Does **both** SOS proof system and resultant approach for $m=n$ (case 1.) give a complexity that scales as $2^{O(n)}poly(nL)$ where $L$ is number of bits to represent the polynomials?

To the system above include hyperplane conditions $H_1,\dots,H_r$ where $r=O(1)$.

**MAIN PROBLEM 2** Resultants do not apply now. Does SOS proof system for $n\ll m=poly(n)$ (case 2.) give a complexity that scales as $2^{O(n)}poly(nL)$ where $L$ is number of bits to represent the polynomials?

Comment: Seventh question this week from this user about systems of homogeneous degree 2 polynomials with integer coefficients. I do wish user would link the questions to each other, since they all bear some similarities.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326240/do-many-homogeneous-polynomials-help-in-faster-integer-root-extraction?noredirect=1#comment814484_326240 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326062/maximum-number-of-bounded-primitive-integer-points-in-a-zero-dimensional-system?noredirect=1#comment814127_326062.